# How to create a list of named lists in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a list of named lists, so that I can iterate over them. This works, but I'm wondering if there isn't a better way.

```
terms = []; usedfors = []; broaders = []; narrowers = []
termlist = [terms, usedfors, broaders, narrowers]
```

The reason for doing it this way is that I have a function `do_some_list_operation(l)` and I want to do something like

```
for i in termlist:
    do_some_list_operation(i)
```

rather than

```
do_some_list_operation(terms)
do_some_list_operation(usedfors)
do_some_list_operation(broaders)
do_some_list_operation(narrowers)
```

I've been searching for 'how to build list of named lists' to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by a named list? Do you mean a `dict` perhaps?

Comment: Your `for` loop looks good to me as is at the moment. unless your termlist is strings like `termlist = ["terms", "usedfors", "broaders", "narrowers"]`

Comment: @msaw328 By named lists I mean each name should reflect what's in them, rather than `mylist[0]`, `mylist[1]`, etc. I chose list because they need to be an ordered collection of strings. I'd use `dict` or `OrderedDict` for key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I like the answer by @jayvee and upvoted it, I think a more conventional answer would be one based on using a dictionary as first suggested by @msaw328.

Starting with our new data structure:

```
term_data = {
    "terms": [1],
    "usedfors": [2],
    "broaders": [3, 4, 5],
    "narrowers": [6, 7]
}
```

Perhaps like:

```
for term in term_data:
    print(f"{term} sums to {sum(term_data[term])}")
```

or even

```
for term, term_value in term_data.items():
    print(f"{term} sums to {sum(term_value)}")
```

Both should give you:

```
terms sums to 1
usedfors sums to 2
broaders sums to 12
narrowers sums to 13
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you are doing it is fine but be aware that you are creating a list of lists when you defined termlist. If you want to have the name of the lists then termlist should be:

```
termlist = ["terms","usedfors", "broaders", "narrowers"]
```

Now if you want to use these strings as list names you can use globals() or locals() e.g.:

```
terms = [1]; usedfors = [2]; broaders = [3,4,8]; narrowers = [5]
termlist = ["terms","usedfors", "broaders", "narrowers"]

for i in termlist:
    print(sum(locals()[i]))
```

output:

```
1
2
15
5
```